# Element created by javascript does not show up on the document

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a div whenever throughout the foreach() the code finds a firebase document that contains the same email that of the user. The code would be a mix of react js and javascript just because I'm a noob to react js. When I check my webpage below div Tickets there is no other div created, and I'm not sure why. What have I done wrong and how should I fix it?

```
import React from "react";
import { authService, dbService } from "../myBase";

const Mypage = () => {
    const user = authService.currentUser;
    const onLogOutClick = () => authService.signOut();

        dbService.collection("performance-1").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            //var noOfOccupied = snapshot.size;
            const seatArray = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                id:doc.id,
                email:doc.data()
            }));

            seatArray.forEach(element => {
                var count = 0;
                if(element.email.toString() === user.email.toString()){
                    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    count = count + 1;
                    const newContent = document.createTextNode(element.id);
                    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
                    const currentDiv = document.getElementById("userTickets");
                    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
                    newDiv.classList.add("Ticket #" + count);
                }
    
            });
        });

        console.log("ticket updated");

    return(
        <body>
            <button className="logout" onClick={onLogOutClick}>Log Out</button>
            <div id = "userTickets">Tickets</div>
        </body>
    )
}

export default Mypage;
```

Comment: React expects you to *render* your elements based on your data. Using regular DOM API's like `insertBefore` should only be used in extreme cases. You should create a state which represents the `id`'s of the matched email addresses and render you elements based on that.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but by any chance could you please show me how I can do this..? (I'm a noob..)

Answer (score 0):

Here below we have an example of how we can do this without using any DOM API's.

React renders its structure based on your data. In your case we'll want to render elements based on the ticket ids.

First create a new state for the tickets with the `useState` hook. In this state we will collect all the ticket ids in an array. Since we don't have any ids yet, set the default value to an empty array `[]`.

Then make your request to the database inside of a `useEffect` hook. This hook enables us to do something **after** the component rerenders. In this case we'll want to make the DB request only **once**. We can do that by giving it an empty dependency array. (In this case we're using `setTickets` in the `useEffect` hook, so we'll need to add that as a dependency. This will still ensure that the `useEffect` hook is only fired once).

When you get your data from the DB, filter out any elements that don't have a matching email. From the remaining elements, extract the `id` and put in a new array. Now you'll have an array of ticket ids. Use `setTickets` to update the state with the received ids.

All there is left is to render the elements based on the content of the `tickets` state.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { authService, dbService } from "../myBase";

const Mypage = () => {
  const user = authService.currentUser;

  /**
   * Create a state for the tickets.
   * At first, we don't have any tickets, 
   * so we'll set an empty array [] as the default value.
   */
  const [tickets, setTickets] = useState([]);

  const onLogOutClick = () => authService.signOut();

  /**
   * You'll only want to get the data once, 
   * whenever the component has rendered for the first time.
   * A useEffect hook will help you with that.  
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    dbService.collection("performance-1").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const seatArray = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        email: doc.data(),
      }));

      /**
       * Loop through the seatArray and find any matching emails
       * We just need the ids from each element.
       * Let's do that with the methods below:
       *
       * filter: Only return elements where the emails match.
       * map: return a new array with just the ids.
       * result = array with ids of the matching emails.
       */
      const tickets = seatArray
        .filter((element) => element.email.toString() === user.email.toString())
        .map((element) => element.id);

      // Update the tickets state.
      setTickets(tickets);
    });
  }, [setTickets]);

  return (
    <body>
      <button className="logout" onClick={onLogOutClick}>
        Log Out
      </button>

      <div id="userTickets">
        <h2>Tickets</h2>

        {/* Loop over the tickets array and output an element for each one. */}
        <ul>
          {tickets.map((ticket, index) => (
            <li className={`Ticket #${index}`}>{ticket}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
  );
};

export default Mypage;
```